# I have lost my JKS file and I cannot restore it

Tags: java, android

I am an Android Amateur developer. I have recently developed an app for business purposes. I have lost my keystore .jks file and i cannot restore it for updating my android app. Is there anyone here to help me how to restore the jks file from a signed APK?? NOTICE: I have not published my app in Google Play store.

Thanks.

Comment: If you have not published you app, simply generate a new one.

Comment: But, no it is impossible to regenerate a signing keypair from a signed object.  (Think.  If it was possible, then it would be trivial for someone to forge a signature.)

Comment: Buddy, research before asking questions on this platform. This question is already there. OK?

Answer (score 2):

You can generate a new jks file. While building apk from android studio, you can set key store path, in that folder you can see your jks file.

But once you upload the app to the play store make sure that you do not lose the JKS file. If you lose then you cannot further update the android app on the play store. JKS file is a unique key for a particular apk so that only those who have the key can update the application. It is for security.

You have not published the app on the play store so no worries. Just generate a new. One more thing, you cannot generate key from a signed apk. You can generate and signed apk and key both at same time. The key will always be same for a particular apk.

It changes only when you change the package name.